# mpiexec.exe is not working with PingPong.exe

Tags: .net, mpi

I am trying to build my own MPI program but the basic mpiexec.exe is not working will
I've installed every thing and follow the instructions like in the [MPI tutorial web site](http://osl.iu.edu/research/mpi.net/documentation/tutorial/)

![mpiexec.exe and now respond][2]

when I terminate the process the following message appears

![mpiexec.exe aborting][3]

Thank you all

//the code is not the problem

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (new MPI.Environment(ref args))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Communicator.world.Rank+" "+ MPI.Environment.ProcessorName+" Hello word");
        }
    }
}}
```

//now try to execute it and build .exe file and run it within cmd like this mpiexec.exe -n 2 ConsoleApplication1.exe

Comment: Please put code in question's text instead of console window screens

Comment: my problem with mpiexec.exe it is just not working probably

Comment: i am doing like in this page http://osl.iu.edu/research/mpi.net/documentation/tutorial/installation.php

Comment: What does PingPong have to do with all of that?

Answer (score 0):

The script for running a MPI code is:

```
 mpiexec -n 2 ConsoleApplication1.exe
```

or

```
 mpirun -np 2 ConsoleApplication1.exe
```

not

> mpiexec.exe

For avoiding problems like this, you can use Linux distributions.